# Error when trying to run class file from Command Prompt

Tags: java

I have this class stored in 
C:/CODE/src/

I open up the CMD and type in

```
C:/CODE/src>java -cp . Hello
```

And then it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello <wrong name: src/hello>
```

The java version is "1.7._02"
I do not know what else to do?
It complies and runs in eclipse IDE but not from the Command Console?

What should I do to rectify this problem?

```
public class Hello {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello");

        }

}
```

Environment Variables

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\;

PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\;

Comment: JAVA_HOME should point to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02, without the bin.

Comment: 1. Have you checked that `Hello.class` is in the `C:\CODE\src` directory? 2. The part of the error saying `<wrong name: src/hello>` suggests to me that you have a `package hello;` statement at the top of your class you haven't shown, is that true?

Comment: what's the package this class in?

Comment: @Aaron What is the statement at line 3 in `Hello.java`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It complies and runs in eclipse IDE but not from the Command Console?

You should be running the command in the dir with the `Hello.class` file
You are running into in the `src` which has only your `Hello.java` file
You will find the `Hello.class` file under `/bin` (that's where Eclipse places them)

Comment: I am running the command when I have cd to the correct directory? It still gives the same error.

Comment: I moved the file to the C:/CODE/src directory which is Hello.class which should be the compiled bytecode file to be interpreted by the java interpreter but it's not finding it?

Comment: Is the `Hello.java` under the default package?

Comment: no I've moved it into a different directory.. does it require the .java file to interpret the code from the Command Promot?

Comment: Do you have a `package hello;` or something similar in the first line of `Hello.java`?

Comment: I have package src as the first line?

Comment: If you have `package src;` in the first line then you should have your class in a dir `src` and run OUTSIDE of `src`: `java src.Hello`

Comment: @Aaron: Then why **don't** you have `package src;` in your quoted code?!?!

Comment: ok so I've moved the class in a directory called src/Hello.class
then in the C:/CODE> I run java src.Hello and I get the following error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problom: at src.Hello.main(Hello.java:3) what does that mean?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: no, he shouldn't use src as a package, since this code was created using Eclipse.  He needs to use the fully qualified path name to the class, minus any package names.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I'm not saying he should. He said *"I have package src as the first line?"* above, but it's not in his posted code. If it's true, the posted code should have the line, anything else is wasting everyone's time. If it isn't true, the comment should be deleted.